# Does elastic-apm collects current cpu usage or average value for the period?

Tags: elastic-apm

I've set up a policy in elastic apm that sends cpu usage data every 10 seconds.
Does it send current cpu usage value or calculates average cpu usage for the last 10 seconds and returns it?